# Quando coloco a tag row Booststrap fica um espaço em branco

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Quando eu coloco a `class "row"` em qualquer documento ele deixa um espaço em branco, já tentei de tudo e o espaço em branco permanece, achei que era o arquivo que estava editando, ai criei esse para ver e aconteceu o mesmo.

```html
<div class="row">
    <h1>title</h1>
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque repudiandae optio ullam itaque corporis fugit sit quas expedita rem quidem, aspernatur voluptates placeat eos earum cupiditate laudantium at odio necessitatibus.</p>
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora officiis nemo, tenetur velit placeat asperiores consequatur vel eaque. Quibusdam non cum libero reprehenderit quis, molestias vero dolorum illum! Sed, inventore.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Já tentou inserir uma `div` **container-fluid** envolvendo a *row*?

Comment: Qual seria o espaço em branco que você esta falando?

Comment: do lado direito, ele ultrapassa a tela

Comment: @LeAndrade tentei e não funcionou, no projeto to usando conteiner

Answer (score -2):

Você pode estar usando uma **container-fluid** ou alterar a class row, adicionando um **padding**

```
.row {
    padding: 10px
}
```

ou

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <h1>title</h1>
        <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque repudiandae optio ullam itaque corporis fugit sit quas expedita rem quidem, aspernatur voluptates placeat eos earum cupiditate laudantium at odio necessitatibus.</p>
        <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora officiis nemo, tenetur velit placeat asperiores consequatur vel eaque. Quibusdam non cum libero reprehenderit quis, molestias vero dolorum illum! Sed, inventore.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: tanto no teste como o projeto continua tendo essa parte em branco, que no projeto estou usando <div class="conteiner">, coloquei conteiner-fluid e continuou persistindo, coloquei o padding de 10px e continuou

Comment: Na resposta acima pelo que vi, o espaço está sendo do lado direito. No exemplo do código, estamos usando duas tags <p>, isso faz com que o texto quebre no final gerando o espaçamento. Se remover a segunda tag <p> deixando o texto ir até o final da margem, assim ele irá quebrar de acordo com a tela.

Comment: o problema não é o paragrafo, esse foi para teste que realmente o que está dando erro é o row, ai queria corrigir o problema, que no meu projeto que ta dando conflito é o row |:

Answer (score -3):

Sua pergunta não ficou muito clara, mas pelo que entendi, é no alinhamento do texto.

Use a propriedade `text-align` do CSS para alinhar o seu texto conforme desejado. Pelo seu problema de "espaçamento" de texto no final, acredito que a melhor opção seria o `text-align: justify`. Ficando assim:

```css
div p {
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <h1>title</h1>
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque repudiandae optio ullam itaque corporis fugit sit quas expedita rem quidem, aspernatur voluptates placeat eos earum cupiditate laudantium at odio necessitatibus.</p>
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora officiis nemo, tenetur velit placeat asperiores consequatur vel eaque. Quibusdam non cum libero reprehenderit quis, molestias vero dolorum illum! Sed, inventore.</p>
</div>
```

Breve explicação do `text-align: justify`:

Os conteúdos são justificados. O texto deve ser espaçado para alinhar suas bordas esquerda e direita com as bordas esquerda e direita da caixa de linha, exceto para a última linha.

Fonte: [MDN - text-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/text-align)

Comment: cara agora fiquei com duvida se é só na minha maquina, mas um site normal ficaria width: 100%, ele meio que ta com width:101% e se coloco 99% ele tira o canto da página

Comment: Testei o código e está normal, acredito que seja algum problema na sua tela mesmo. Tentou usar outro navegador?